# How do define label system with labels given by counter?

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

I would like to have two commands `\makelabel{foo}` and `\referlabel{foo}` to be used as in the example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \[ A \overset{\makelabel{foo}}{=} B \overset{\makelabel{bar}}{=} C \]
 where \referlabel{foo} is given by \ldots and \referlabel{bar} is given by \ldots
\[ C \overset{\makelabel{foobar}}{=} D\]
Equality \referlabel{foobar} \ldots
\end{document}
```

such that the output is the same as for the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \[ A \overset{(1)}{=} B \overset{(2)}{=} C \]
 where (1) is given by \ldots and (2) is given by \ldots
\[ C \overset{(3)}{=} D\]
Equality (3) \ldots
\end{document}
```

That is, the label should be created from a counter. Possibly, `\referlabel{foo}` should create a hyperlink to `\makelabel{foo}`.
Could you point me to existing solutions or indicate how to implement the commands, please?

Answer (score 6):

`\makelabel` is already a known command, so I've changed the interface to `\setlabel`/`\reflabel`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{labelcnt}
\renewcommand{\thelabelcnt}{(\arabic{labelcnt})}
\newcommand{\setlabel}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{labelcnt}\ltx@label{lbl:#1}%
  {\text{\upshape\thelabelcnt}}%
}
\newcommand{\reflabel}[1]{\text{\upshape\ref{lbl:#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
  A \overset{\setlabel{foo}}{=} B \overset{\setlabel{bar}}{=} C
\]
where~\reflabel{foo} is given by \ldots and~\reflabel{bar} is given by \ldots
\[
  C \overset{\setlabel{foobar}}{=} D
\]
Equality~\reflabel{foobar} \ldots

\end{document}
```

To avoid a "Multiple `\label`" error with the loading of [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), we use the traditional LaTeX `\label` macro, stored in `\ltx@label`.

Comment: Would it suffice to just use `\eqref` instead of defining a new `\reflabel`?

Comment: @KevinC: Since it would syntactically not refer to an equation, but an equality, I kept the interface, even though it should work.